# One Page website with carousel-like navigation with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am making a page with horizontal navigation, and it works fine. But now I need to add some animation. I want to add carousel-like navigation. So when a visitor clicks on “Download” button, all the content scrolled from right to left and if the visitor clicks “Home” it goes back but with left-to-right animation. I would also like it navigate between the pages when a visitor starts to scroll.

I googled for some solutions but have not found nothing but a css-animation that ignores the order of slides and performs always one way sliding. I am new to angular and I will appreciate any help.

Here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app=“opw">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#”>One page website</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="how_does_it_work”>How does it work?</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="wanted”>Wanted</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="app”>Download app</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>


<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the `app.js`

```
angular.module(‘opw', ['ui.router'])
    // router configuration
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'template/homepage/home.html'
            })

            // HOW-DOES-IT-WORK PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
            .state('how_does_it_work', {
                url: ‘/how-does-it-work',
                templateUrl: 'template/homepage/hdiw.html'
            })

            // WANTED PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
            .state('wanted', {
                url: ‘/wanted',
                templateUrl: 'template/homepage/wanted.html'
            })


            // DOWNLOAD-APP PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
            .state('app', {
                url: ‘/download',
                templateUrl: 'template/homepage/app.html',
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/homerjam/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out) 
This will animate your state transitions
Now this doesn't do what you exactly want,

- You want the animation to reverse when the direction of navigation is reversed -  To achieve I suggest you use ng-class to apply the class according to the direction of navigation.
- You want the animation to cycle through all the states before it on press of home - Now this can be achieved by using a stack data structure and just pushing all the states as your move forward and when home is pressed pop the elements of the stack and transition to that state, do this until home is reached/stack is empty.

Hope this points you in the right direction. Happy coding.

Cheers